# How to split values from the field in AS/400?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a field with different code, for example: 52, 53, 5253, 54, 5354 and 52,54. I need to split 4-digits to first two and second two. I have no idea how to do this in as/400. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: as/400 is a machine platform.  What programming language?

Answer (score 2):

use the `%subst` opcode in RPG to access characters within a larger character fields.

```
d ch4             s              4a   
d ch2a            s              2a   
d ch2b            s              2a   
 /free                                
      ch4         = '5253' ;          
      ch2a        = %subst(ch4:1:2) ; 
      ch2b        = %subst(ch4:3:2) ; 
 /end-free
```

if the data you are looking for is delimited by a comma, use %scan to find the delimiter and then use %subst to extract the subfield based on the location of the delimiter.

```
d ch5             s              5a       
d ch2a            s              2a       
d ch2b            s              2a       
d fx              s             10i 0     
 /free                                    
      ch5         = '52,53' ;             
      ch2a        = %subst(ch5:1:2) ;     
      fx          = %scan( ',': ch5 ) ;   
      if          fx > 0 ;                
      ch2b        = %subst(ch5:fx+1:2) ;  
      endif ;                             
 /end-free
```

to do this in fixed format RPG:

```
d ch5             s              5a                          
d ch2a            s              2a                          
d ch2b            s              2a                          
d ch3             s              3a                          
d arr5            s              1a   dim(5)                 
                                                             
** original RPG. the MOVE, MOVEL, MOVEA opcodes.             
c* MOVE - move from the right.  MOVEL - move from the left.  
c                   move      '52,53'       ch5              
c                   move      ch5           ch2b             
c                   movel     ch5           ch2a             
                                                             
** MOVEA - move to or from array                             
c                   movea     ch5           ar5              
c                   movea     ar5(4)        ch2b             
                                                             
** before free form in RPG there was the EVAL opcode.        
c                   eval      ch5 = '52,53'                  
c                   eval      ch2a = %subst(ch5:1:2)         
c                   eval      fx = %scan(',':ch5)            
c                   if        fx > 0                         
c                   eval      ch2b = %subst(ch5:fx+1:2)      
c                   endif
```

Comment: [`%split`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-split-split-string-into-substrings) also exists since 7.4 TR4 and T.3 TR10

Comment: Thanks RockBoro for explaining. Could you also share how to do this in SEU without using fully free form.

Answer (score 0):

Translate the prototype of [strTok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) you can find a HowTo [here](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/callc.html).